# SELECT Query Not Working when selecting particular column 'condition'

Tags: mysql, sql, select

TBL_condition

```
  ID CONDITION
  1     AAA
  2     BBB
  3     CCC
```

When I hit this query:

```
    SELECT CONDITION FROM TBL_condition
```

It says:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition from tbl_condition' at line 1

Comment: have you tried like this--`SELECT 'CONDITION' FROM 'TBL_condition'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using backticks (`) around CONDITION :

```
SELECT `CONDITION` FROM `TBL_condition`;
```

Condition is a term used by mysql. read more on this site: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,40643,40643

Answer (score 3):

CONDITION is reserved word in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

try like this

```
SELECT `CONDITION` FROM TBL_condition
```

Answer (score 3):

This might have to do with CONDITION being a function in SQL. You have to put it like this `CONDITION` to prevent such things.

Answer (score 0):

CONDITION is a reserved word for MySQL. it is used as for declare a condition like:

```
DECLARE condition_name CONDITION FOR condition_value
```

so you need to use backticks(`) around in any reserved word in your any query.like:

```
`CONDITION`
```